# how to check the middleware in blade view

Tags: laravel

in my navbar I am using @guest and @auth to hide some navbar links from the guests,
now I need to show some links to the admin, how to make this?

the Admin middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin == 1) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

Comment: You can use `@if(Auth::user()->is_admin)` or make a custom [blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#extending-blade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use laravel gate
go to App/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php
and write this code inside boot function of provider it make a gate

```
Gate::define("Admin",function(User $user){
      if($user->is_admin){
         return true;
      }
      return false; 
});
```

note:- use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate; at the top of provider

now your gate is ready:-
inside your blade you can check a user is admin or not using @can

```
@can('Admin')
   "write something which only admin see"
 @endcan
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in all laravel versions:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    // User is authenticated...
@else
    // User is not authenticated...
@endif
```

**Laravel > 5.5**:

```
@auth
    // user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
    // User is not authenticated...
@endguest

``
```